# UIKit - Calendar components return absolute value for a negative year

Tags: swift, date, swiftui, calendar, uikit

I'm having trouble with extracting the `year` from a `Date`. Everything works fine until I use a date that has a negative year. Then UIKit's `Calendar.componten(:from:)` returns the absolute value instead and is even off by 1. Here's an example:

```swift
import UIKit

let calendar = Calendar.current

let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: -90000000000)
print(date) // -0882-01-14 08:00:00 +0000
print(calendar.component(.year, from: date)) // 883
```

Any idea why that happens and how to correctly get the date without manually trying to figure out the year's sign?

Thanks!

Comment: just wonder why you need to use a negative year ?

Comment: For a fictional timeline, basically. I'm quite sure I won't need negative years but it would drive me crazy knowing that I couldn't do it if I did eventually need it.

Comment: hmm it is a good idea for calculating the age of the our planet, btw it is used for negative years B.S 9000 not "- 9000" . but yeah you are a programmer so everything is possible :)

Comment: ok, you just answered the question for me haha :D You're right, I've never thought about that :D Turns out, the calendar has an `era` component that is exactly responsible for that. Thanks! Care to post it as an answer, then I'll accept it. Here's a link I found after googling for BC and AD in UIKits calendar:  https://nshipster.com/datecomponents/#era-and-year

Comment: good job :) ok i drop an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative years should be present as B.S 9000 not "- 9000". In Swift there is era instance property as well. You can create your calendar and play with the values For example :

```
var newCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
newCalendar.timeZone = newCalendarTimeZone

let newCalendarEra = newCalendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .era, for: now)
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents/1416364-era